# Losing review comments on pushing code again

Tags: github, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Sonarqube with the Github plugin for analysing code in Pull Requests.

I get a problem when pushing code if the PR is already open. The comments made by the Github plugin in the PR are erased even if the new push doesn't fix them! Apparently because only the modified code gets analysed, and the other comments by the issue reporter user are erased. It means I'm losing the previously reported issues.

Any ideas on how to maintain the comments for the issues I still haven't solved in new commit/pushes?

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem was to make some additional changes on the files in my first commit.

This happened to me also. I had 1 commit when I opened the pull request, tons of issues were noted. I made a second small commit to update an unrelated configuration file, this caused sonar to remove all of the comments. I tried everything I could think of to get it to scan the full pull request: Closed/re-opened the pull request, ran the sonar preview scan again manually, reverted my 2nd commit (which created a 3rd commit).

We have git send us email reports of any comments made on our pull requests, so we had a record of all the sonar comments. We made some changes to the original files based on these comments and once we committed our fixes, sonar ran against the original files and the rest of the sonar comments popped back up!

This created a new best practice for us. If sonar finds any issues, the next commit should be fixes for those issues.

Comment: The new best practice tip is good. However, I'm not sure ensuring every next commits to solve it is a good practice for us. It's too much of a loose rule, it may get flawed at some point. We have noticed upon updating the SonarJava plugin that the problem stopped happening at least for Java analysis! The main difference on this new plugin is that bytecode is now analysed.